# how i can take autosize for the second fxml inside main fxml

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

how i can load my second fxml in my first fxml

Comment: All [`autosize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#autosize--) does is resizing the node to it's preferred size. If the node keeps this size or not depends on the layout you add it to (`setting_page` in this case).

Comment: Hi Mr Fabian i do it but is show me error so give the perfect solution for this cause

Comment: Thanks Mr fabian i solved i edited my question

Comment: Please give your question more detail... Some code you may already have

Comment: Dear Developer my question it was how i can load my second fxml inside first fxml and how i can resize the second fxml when i resizing my first fxml  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you most but for Main AnchorPane in each controller

this code inside fxml

```
  <AnchorPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="520" prefWidth="782.0" style="-fx-background-color: White; -fx-background-radius: 15px; -fx-border-radius: 12px;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller.CreateitemController">
```

then in main screen but this code for open the second screen inside main screen when click the button

```
@FXML
    public void groupshow(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FX/creategroupshow.fxml"));
        setting_page.getChildren().setAll(root);

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PklMq.png)